# Remove all \n between triple quotes

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex pattern that matches **any number** of occurrences of something within something else. For example regarding the following code:

```
'''\n           <html>\n         <body>\n           <p>Your file successfully uploaded</p>\n         </body>\n       </html>\n       '''
```

Here, I am interested to match every `\n` between `'''`s. my desired output is as follows:

```
'''           <html>         <body>           <p>Your file successfully uploaded</p>         </body>       </html>       '''
```

I can break the problem to find anything `.*` between triple quotes then simply replace `\n`s. But I am looking to find a better way to possibly apply at once. All of my attempts such as the following just find or substitute one of the `\n`s.

```
re.findall('(?<=\'\'\').+(\\n)+[^\\n]+(?=\'\'\')', text, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: In "*any number of occurrences of something within something else*", what are "something" and "something else" in your example? Do you just want to remove `\n`s from string?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Please read the body of question. I have provided and example. No, I want to remove every \ns within for example ().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with custom `repl` as a function:

```
import re
text = "'''\n           <html>\n         <body>\n           <p>Your file successfully uploaded</p>\n         </body>\n       </html>\n       ''' Don't replace this\n new line"
result = re.sub("\'\'\'[^\']*\'\'\'", lambda x: x.group(0).replace('\n',''), text)
```

Comment: Good idea but this will fail if one of the triple quoted parts contains a single quote. Change `[^']*` (no need to escape the quote), to `[^']*(?:'(?!'{2})[^']*)*` (a quote not followed by two other quotes) or a simple `.*?` in singleline mode. Also take care that `'\n'` and `"\n"` are not the same.